Why is ComplexExpand[HeavisideTheta[0]] == 1 while HeavisideTheta[0] is left undefined?
The following code:
ComplexExpand[HeavisideTheta[0]] 
HeavisideTheta[0]

returns
1
HeavisideTheta[0]

Why when using ComplexExpand is the value of the Heaviside function at 0 assumed to be 1? It seems in the documentation that it is left undefined...

The HeavisedeTheta is an attempt to implement the certain distribution (generalized function) in Mathematica, not a usual function. Its value at its support makes no sense. Such questions were asked and answered many times in this forum.

See Wiki as a first reading to this end.

Because for some reason ComplexExpand[HeavisideTheta[x]] // FullForm returns UnitStep[x] which is 1 for x=0.  I don't know whether that is a bug or a feature.

Strange indeed... Thanks a lot!

I don’t know either…

I plead for a bug

@UlrichNeumann Compromise on a beature?

@DanielLichtblau Didn't get your comment. Perhaps my wording wasn't correct...

I was using a colloquialism that melds “bug” and “feature”. I didn’t invent the term, and perhaps it’s only used in the US. Anyway, it was not meant to be taken seriously so not to worry.

Thanks for your explanation
